# FileNotFoundException with Titan (titan-all)

Tags: groovy, titan, gremlin, gremlin-server

I'm trying to set up a basic Titan example. In following the docs, I tried running `bin/gremlin-server.sh -i com.thinkaurelius.titan titan-all 1.0.0` which throws;

```
Could not install the dependency: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/titan/ext/titan-all/plugin/titan-all-1.0.0.jar (No such file or directory)
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/titan/ext/titan-all/plugin/titan-all-1.0.0.jar (No such file or directory)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.util.DependencyGrabber.getAdditionalDependencies(DependencyGrabber.groovy:165)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.util.DependencyGrabber.copyDependenciesToPath(DependencyGrabber.groovy:99)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.GremlinServerInstall.main(GremlinServerInstall.java:38)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/titan/ext/titan-all/plugin/titan-all-1.0.0.jar (No such file or directory)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.util.DependencyGrabber.getAdditionalDependencies(DependencyGrabber.groovy:148)
    ... 3 more
```

I also tried it from gremlin.sh;

```
root@ubuntu:/usr/share/titan# bin/gremlin.sh

         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
plugin activated: aurelius.titan
plugin activated: tinkerpop.server
plugin activated: tinkerpop.utilities
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/share/titan/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/share/titan/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
14:45:44 INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.HadoopGraph  - HADOOP_GREMLIN_LIBS is set to: /usr/share/titan/lib
plugin activated: tinkerpop.hadoop
plugin activated: tinkerpop.tinkergraph
gremlin> :install com.thinkaurelius.titan titan-all 1.0.0
==>java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/titan/ext/titan-all/plugin/titan-all-1.0.0.jar (No such file or directory)
gremlin>
```

I've confirmed that groovy has the file;

```
root@ubuntu:/usr/share/titan# ls ~/.groovy/grapes/com.thinkaurelius.titan/titan-all/jars
titan-all-1.0.0.jar
```

So now I'm stumped.. Has anyone come across this before?

**EDIT: Some notes on how I got here..**

My first attempt at getting this working was to use the all-inclusive zip file as per the docs... I changed gremlin-server.yaml to;

```
graph: conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties
```

That threw;

```
407  [main] WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  - Graph [graph] configured at [conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties] could not be instantiated and will not be available in Gremlin Server.  GraphFactory message: Configuration must contain a valid 'gremlin.graph' setting
java.lang.RuntimeException: Configuration must contain a valid 'gremlin.graph' setting
```

Ok, simple google search tells me I need to add this to conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties;

```
gremlin.graph=com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory
```

At which point, I get..

```
484  [main] WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  - Graph [graph] configured at [conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties] could not be instantiated and will not be available in Gremlin Server.  GraphFactory message: GraphFactory could not instantiate this Graph implementation [class com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory]
java.lang.RuntimeException: GraphFactory could not instantiate this Graph implementation [class com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory]
```

This leads me to believe that I'm missing `com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory`. Which is curious, since $TITAN_HOME/lib does in fact contain titan-all-1.0.0.jar. So I assumed (perhaps wrongly) that I need to run the titan-all install to make it actually load the jars..

Answer (score 1):

The basic install for Titan is unzip the titan-1.0.0-hadoop1.zip. That is it!

Download it from http://titandb.io

http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/getting-started.html

It is already packaged with the Titan plugins, so you don't need to install them into the Gremlin Console or Gremlin Server.

If you want to try the Titan Server, there is a pre-packaged `titan.sh` script which automatically starts Cassandra and Elasticsearch with the server.

http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/server.html#_getting_started

Comment: Jason, just replied on the list to you, but updating my question here for others..

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that comes across this strangeness, read the whole stack trace. It turns out waaay at the bottom, it actually had the real issue; it couldn't connect to Cassandra because I had not enabled Thrift.